# Programmatically line up two views at a corner

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-imageview, android-view

So this seems like a very simple question, but I can't figure out how to get the proper location after scaling a view.

I'm trying to line up an imageView to the bottom right corner of another imageView. This code works fine if I don't modify `firstImageView`.

```
secondImageView.setX(firstImageView.getRight());
secondImageView.setY(firstImageView.getBottom());
```

But then after I apply a translation or scale to the firstImageView, the code above doesn't seem to work correctly (doesn't line up at corners). I'm guessing that scaling doesn't affect the actual size of the view, even though it's clearly resized. So how would I go about setting the secondImageView to the bottom right of the firstImageView even after scale, rotation and/or translation have been modified?

**EDIT: two views at a corner code**

```
firstImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            float startX, startY;
            float translationX, translationY;
            float startMoveX, startMoveY;



            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

                if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    secondImageView.setX(imageView.getRight());
                    secondImageView.setY(imageView.getBottom());
                    secondImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    startX = e.getRawX();
                    startY = e.getRawY();

                    startMoveX = firstImageView.getX();
                    startMoveY = firstImageView.getY();




                } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                    translationX = e.getRawX() - startX + startMoveX;
                    translationY = e.getRawY() - startY + startMoveY;
                    firstImageView.setTranslationX(translationX);
                    firstImageView.setTranslationY(translationY);


                    secondImageView.setTranslationX(firstImageView.getX()+firstImageView.getMeasuredWidth());
                    secondImageView.setTranslationY(firstImageView.getY()+firstImageView.getMeasuredHeight());

                } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

**scaling code:**

```
secondImageView.setScaleX(2);
secondImageView.setScaleY(2);
```

Comment: We need more information before we can help you.  What does "doesn't seem to work correctly." mean (i.e. what are you seeing).  Also, post the relevant code (parent layout, scaling, rotations, etc.) otherwise you will get wild guesses rather than helpful answers.

Comment: The code listed works. It lines the top left of the second imageView to the bottom right of the first imageView. After I setScale(2-10) on firstImageView calling that code doesn't put the secondImageView on the bottom right anymore.

Comment: Where does it place it then?  Directly on top, centered, offset, etc.?  A picture would help if you can get one.

Comment: I call the code above every time onClick of firstImageView. The second image view sets itself to the getRight and getBottom of the original position of the firstImageView.

Comment: Are you scaling the second image ? secondImageView.setScaleX

Comment: No. The only view scaled is firstImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption.  **Translation does not affect the bounds of the view**.  However if you calculate the position offset (delta) of the second view from the first at the beginning of the gesture, you can translate both views at once.  Here's a **working sample** that you can use.

#### activity_test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/photo"/>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo_two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/photo"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

  private static String TAG = "TestActivity";
  private ImageView mPhoto;
  private ImageView mPhotoTwo;
  private float mStartX;
  private float mStartY;
  private float mDeltaX;
  private float mDeltaY;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    mPhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
    mPhotoTwo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_two);

    mPhoto.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
        boolean result = false;
        int action = e.getAction();

        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

          mStartX = e.getX();
          mStartY = e.getY();
          mDeltaX = mPhoto.getWidth() - mPhotoTwo.getWidth();
          mDeltaY = mPhoto.getHeight() - mPhotoTwo.getHeight();
          result = true;

        }else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

          float x = e.getX();
          float y = e.getY();
          float deltaX = x - mStartX;
          float deltaY = y - mStartY;

          float viewX = view.getX();
          float viewY = view.getY();
          float valueX = deltaX + viewX;
          float valueY = deltaY + viewY;

          mPhoto.setX(valueX);
          mPhoto.setY(valueY);

          float valueTwoX = valueX + mDeltaX;
          float valueTwoY = valueY + mDeltaY;

          mPhotoTwo.setX(valueTwoX);
          mPhotoTwo.setY(valueTwoY);

          result = true;
        }

        return result;

      }
    });
  }
}
```

## UPDATE

Per request I'm modifying the code to remove all layout_align properties from the layout files.  All positioning (including the initial rendering of the view) will be done programatically.

#### activity_test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/photo"/>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo_two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

  private static String TAG = "TestActivity";
  private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
  private ImageView mPhoto;
  private ImageView mPhotoTwo;
  private float mStartX;
  private float mStartY;
  private float mDeltaX;
  private float mDeltaY;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
    mPhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
    mPhotoTwo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_two);

    ViewTreeObserver observer = mRelativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        float viewX = mPhoto.getX();
        float viewY = mPhoto.getY();

        mDeltaX = mPhoto.getWidth() - mPhotoTwo.getWidth();
        mDeltaY = mPhoto.getHeight() - mPhotoTwo.getHeight();

        float valueTwoX = viewX + mDeltaX;
        float valueTwoY = viewY + mDeltaY;

        mPhotoTwo.setX(valueTwoX);
        mPhotoTwo.setY(valueTwoY);
      }
    });


    mPhoto.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
        boolean result = false;
        int action = e.getAction();

        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

          mStartX = e.getX();
          mStartY = e.getY();
          result = true;

        }else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

          float x = e.getX();
          float y = e.getY();
          float deltaX = x - mStartX;
          float deltaY = y - mStartY;

          float viewX = view.getX();
          float viewY = view.getY();
          float valueX = deltaX + viewX;
          float valueY = deltaY + viewY;

          mPhoto.setX(valueX);
          mPhoto.setY(valueY);

          float valueTwoX = valueX + mDeltaX;
          float valueTwoY = valueY + mDeltaY;

          mPhotoTwo.setX(valueTwoX);
          mPhotoTwo.setY(valueTwoY);

          result = true;
        }

        return result;

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try/implement your method in a few minutes, but since you seemed to have confirmed my assumption saying "Translation does not affect the bounds of the view" wouldn't something like view.invalidate() redraw and recalculate the bounds?

Comment: invalidate() causes the OS to do extra work by requesting another round of sizing and drawing.  In an animation loop that can be taxing on the CPU. You could end up with Android JANK - especially on older single core devices with minimal available memory.  The animation classes were created for this reason.  Get to know them because they are the simplest and most reliable way of animating views. You won't need to worry about invalidating views and your apps will be JANK free.  The code above is a working sample.  Just copy, paste and run.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: Also, does it make a difference of what the parent viewgroup is? I'm undecided what to use. I feel as though since I'm moving items around, I should use an absolute layout... but that is deprecated.

Comment: As my last comment. I'm not trying to "animate" my views. I'm trying to let my users drag and drop a view around on the screen. The only problem being that the view needs to have this other view in the bottom right at all times.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I did not see the onTouch event.  After thinking about it you could still use the MarginProxy to get this done.  I'll try to create a sample for you.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  My apologies for misunderstanding the question.  I was able to get it to work with translation only.

Comment: Thanks itsben. Will try it out now.

Comment: Did it work for you?  You should be able to copy, paste and run.

Comment: This is closer to what I'm trying to accomplish, but I don't want to set up the relation of the "corner" in xml. I wanted to do this programatically. Which is what I thought I was hinting at with the title of the question. "Programmatically line up two views at a corner" Sorry if I made it more difficult to understand.

Comment: I'm going to update the answer again.  Two lines of XML code is saving you 50 lines of Java code.

Comment: How about that bounty? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Would upvote but that requires 15 reputation. hah. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Initially the layout was drawn using the first image scale. Later on scale changes you need to redraw the layout to effect the changes you made.

on scale change run 
     requestLayout() or invalidate()

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
```

If in the course of processing the event, the view's bounds may need to be changed, the view will call requestLayout().

Similarly, if in the course of processing the event the view's appearance may need to be changed, the view will call invalidate().

If either requestLayout() or invalidate() were called, the framework will take care of measuring, laying out, and drawing the tree as appropriate.

Comment: I get a null pointer exception when I added the code you suggested. I tried firstImageView.invalidate() because thats the view that gets scaled, but it still didn't help.

Comment: are you tried findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate()?

Comment: Yes. `findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate()` gave me a null pointer.

Comment: Post your code. on which event you are scaling the image?